# Change value of environment on angular build production

Tags: angular, environment-variables, angular-cli

I want to change one of the values inside my environment file during the build of my project for production, I want to know if something like this is possible?

for instance, run something  like the below code

```
ng build --configuration=production --version=1.1.1
```

version part be copied to my environment.prod.ts file before building begins

```
export const environment = {
   production: true,
   version: '0.0.0'
};
```

Comment: Angular CLI currently doesn't support this out of the box. But you can simply use pre-build / after-build scripts to achieve it. There are multiple ways to do this, with some examples listed in [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4318) topic.